# Extention OmniPascal (vscode) using too much CPU - How to resolve?

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnipascal

Every time I start vscode, OminiPascalServer.exe start to use 35 to 50% of CPU process.
This appears not only in my computer, but with every person I know who use this extention.
Exist some configuration to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: The correct place to report this issue would be [their bugtracker](https://bitbucket.org/Wosi/omnipascalissues/issues/82/omnipascalserverexe-high-cpu-usage).

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens at the start as OmniPascal probably need to scan through the entire workspace. So one way to quicken the process is to reduce the amount of things it need to scan.

This is how I do it and I notices a drastic improvement:

- Create a new VSCode workspace that only focuses on Pascal files
- In your VSCode workspace, add relevant folders
- In Settings > Files > Exclude, exclude all irrelevant items in your Pascal project. (I don't know if this actually matters, but it seems to help)
- In the case that you want to add external library, rather than adding them as part of your workspace, you can add them in Settings > OmniPascal > Search Path. You might also need to change the Symbol Index to select "searchPath"